# How to create a sub branch?

Tags: git, branch

My git repository has two branches, `master` and `bug`. I want to create a branch `bug/rep`. So I run :

```
git branch bug/rep
```

This gives the error:

> error: unable to resolve reference refs/heads/bug/rep: Not a directory
>   fatal: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/heads/bug/rep'.

How can I create a sub branch from the `bug` branch, like `bug/rep`?
My git version is 2.3.2 on the Mac.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In git, branches correspond to actual files in a hierarchy in the `.git` subdirectory. If you create a branch named `bug/sub`, git will first create a folder `.git/refs/heads/bug` (if it doesn't already exist) and within that folder it will create a file named `sub` which is the branch. Branch names are presumed to resolve within `.git/refs/heads`, so `refs/heads` + `bug/sub` resolves to a real place in the file system.

The trouble that you're encountering comes from your file system. Since you already have a branch called `bug`, in `.git/refs/heads` there is *already* a file named `bug`. Creating the sub branch as outlined above would require the file system to create a new folder named `bug`, but it can't because there is already a file there named `bug`.

In brief, you're free to create a hierarchy of branches, but higher-level nodes of your hierarchy can't be branches in their own right.

Answer (score 5):

for creating a new sub branch 
`git checkout -b <sub-branch-name>` 
 // sub branch will automatically created at the time of push

 for pushing file on sub branch created earlier 
`git push -u origin <sub-branch-name>`
-u for setting upstream parameter

here origin is the master branch, added with

```
git add remote origin master https://github.com/<ur-name>/repoName.git
```

checkout the name of branches

```
git branch
```

Comment: FYI: the reason I don't trust your answer is that it doesn't clearly state how this is makes the sub-branch instead of just a branch off of main. 

Not saying your wrong (because I'm a newbie at github), just that as a newbie the answer doesn't give me enough warm fuzzy feelings to use it.

Source: I'm trying to make a sub-branch right now, and so far have only made branches off of main

Comment: This is wrong. This is just generic information on how to create any branch. It will not create a sub-branch as you have asked for.

Comment: Indeed, this is clearly not an answer to the question. Maybe the answer can be improved to show how to make a sub branch with commands? It will be a nice addition to @Daniel Kessler's answer.